# How can I adjust the apparent color temperature of my display in OS X?

Tags: macos, display, color

I really like [**f.lux**](http://stereopsis.com/flux/), which is an app that automatically adjusts the display's apparent color temperature according to the time of day and location (so that the temperature is in sync with Sun).

**How to set the color temperature *manually?*** I.e. without f.lux?

Sometimes I'd like to have "tungsten" (2700 K) colors during the day or morning, which would require fiddling with the location coordinates in f.lux. Sadly, there's no "manual mode" that I'm aware of.

I'm looking for a OS X native / software based solution, that would allow me to set white point below 4500 °K, which is the minimum that Color Calibrator can set. Is this even possible?

Comment: Fellow f.lux user here. Great app. Best I know w/o 3rd party software or using the monitor's buttons would be to go System Preferences > Displays > Color > Calibrate. Use "Expert Mode". However this will only let you take it down to 4500 K. Interested to find out the answer on this one.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the difficulty, but can't you just set F.lux's daytime slider to 2700? When you say "sometimes", do you mean algorithmically predictable times/dates? If so, then a script would solve your problem. I think it's possible to write a script to force F.lux to a certain daytime temp (or nighttime for that matter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution requires F.lux to be installed (I assume it's at `/Applications/Flux.app`).

Create a text file (let's call it `flux-day-color`) and put it in `/usr/local/bin` (`usr` is under "Macintosh HD" and may be hidden).

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -z "$1" && "$1" -ge 2700 && "$1" -le 6500 ]]; then
  defaults write org.herf.Flux dayColorTemp -int "$1"
  killall Flux
  open /Applications/Flux.app
else
  echo "provide a temperature between 2700 and 6500 (rounded to nearest 100)"
fi
```

In Terminal, run `chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/flux-day-color`

Now you can run `flux-day-color 2700` in Terminal (or in another script) to change the day temperature. Note that the script restarts F.lux so you may see the display jump to 6500 K for a split second before applying your requested temperature.

It's also possible to schedule this to run at predefined intervals, but that's beyond the scope of this answer (and the question).

If you'd rather have a launchable app that can toggle between 2 temperatures,

Open Terminal and run these commands:

```
bash
cd /Applications/
mkdir -p flux-day-toggle.app/Contents/MacOS
cd flux-day-toggle.app/Contents/MacOS
cat <<END > flux-day-toggle
```

Now you'll see a greater than sign. Paste this:

```
#!/bin/bash

DOMAIN=org.herf.Flux
KEY_NAME=dayColorTemp

LOW=2700
HIGH=6500

cur_val=`defaults read $DOMAIN $KEY_NAME 2>/dev/null`
if [[ -z "$cur_val" || "$cur_val" -eq "$HIGH" ]]; then
  new_val=$LOW
else
  new_val=$HIGH
fi

defaults write $DOMAIN $KEY_NAME -int $new_val
killall Flux
open /Applications/Flux.app
END
```

Wait for the prompt to appear, meaning the file was written.
Now the finishing touch:

```
chmod 755 flux-day-toggle
```

Now you can launch the new app. You can customize the LOW and HIGH settings to your liking.

Comment: Here's a bonus tip: a command-line utility to set the display brightness (ie in lieu of the F1 and F2 keys). http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090901021817717

Comment: @koiyu: I used your Gist to manually alter F.lux and it has worked well, thank you. However, I now cannot alter the brightness of my screen using the keypad -- is it possible that this is related to your Gist?

Comment: @user27182 Don't think so — at least my external Apple BT keyboard alters brightness normally even when temperature is being adjusted. All the actions the script does is (1) kill f.lux (2) set f.lux preferences (3) re-open f.lux. It's more likely to be related to f.lux or just a random operating system mishap (ie. have you tried turning it off and on again?)

Comment: **Reposted due to link rot:** Had to check this as an accepted answer as I haven't got Nocturne to work on Mavericks. I enhanced your flux-day-color script a bit and [created a Gist](https://gist.github.com/keinajar/7398527) that can be used to set either/both day and night temperatures (and just using flux-temp 3000, i.e. without options, to change the current display temperature to whatever regardless of the time.) I also found out the minimum Flux temperature is 2300 K, at least in the current version.

Comment: @JariKeinänen If you switch your `killall` in your gist to `killall -1 Flux`, move it to the bottom of the script (where the `open` command current is), and remove the `open` command, Flux won't steal focus when the script is run. I'm running it in a cronjob to hopefully prevent burning on my OLED monitor so not losing focus is super handy. Cron for reference: `bash flux.sh -l | grep customNightColorTemp | awk '{print $3}' | awk -F\; '{print $1}' | xargs python -c 'import sys; import random; print(min(max(int(sys.argv[1]) + random.randint(-400, 400), 2700), 6500))' | xargs bash flux.sh`

Answer (score 7):

When using the Displays section of your System Preferences, if you calibrate it, select show advanced options, one of the windows is this:
[image] which to me looks like the white points you were looking for, be sure to uncheck "Use native white point" if you want to manually edit it.

Comment: Great info, thanks. I hadn't had the guts to go through all the steps just for the white point. Sadly, though, the lowest kelvin is 4500-4700 (just closed the window ><). Is there a way to adjust *just* the white point? (well, I could calibrate different profiles) And how to adjust it below the Calibrator's options?

Comment: I found the value hardcoded in /Users/username/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ColorSyncCalibrator.plist, but editing it to a lower value had no effect. I will keep looking.

Comment: It did have an affect when I logged in and out, I was able to black out my entire monitor, so probably relauching something will reset the value

Comment: I think I am going to need to ask my own question, something along the lines of what actions are the sys prefs taking after loading that file to tell the mac to activate the change besides changing the file.

Answer (score 4):

Found a possible workaround for those who are interested:

### [Nocturne by Blacktree](http://www.blacktree.com/)

[image: Nocturne preferences]

It has a nice amount of options and is completely manual. Downside is it doesn't set apparent color temperature *per se*, but setting a *white tint* to `RGB(255, 197, 143)` has approximately the same effect as setting white point to ≈ 2600 °K (see [Kelvin ⇔ RGB table on planetpixelemporium](http://planetpixelemporium.com/tutorialpages/light.html)).

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) Thanks! I found it's [latest release on GitHub](https://github.com/nocturneapp/nocturne/releases) in both binary and source forms (while a lot of other tools cost money just to install).

Answer (score 0):

Open system preferences, go to the Displays panel and choose the Color tab. Press the Calibrate... button and go through the steps. If you turn on expert mode, you will choose the white point using a slider, but if you don't you will get to choose between a few standard values. You can even do this multiple times, saving with a different name each time, and switch between them through the list in the color tab.

Comment: Sadly, the lowest target white's are somewhere 4500–4700 °K. Do you know how to tune it down to, say, 2700 °K?

Answer (score -1):

A cool way is to let f.lux do the work http://stereopsis.com/flux/ It adjusts your screen colour temp. with the time of the day! Give it a try!

Comment: I think you missed the part of his question where he said "without f.lux."

Comment: oh sorry... I realized it when I just had posted my answer