# Software Screen Tinting, or Colour Overlay for Mac Users with Dyslexia

Tags: macos, color, accessibility

There are students at the school I work at who are dyslexic, and have the specific strand of dyslexia which doesn't deal well with black text on a white background. One way you overcome this with print is you put a coloured film over the text you're reading - and it really **amazing** how it improves their comprehension and their fluency (you can see an example of the overlay [here](http://www.dyslexiacure.com/)).

I'm looking for a way to 'tint' the screen with software in the same manner on the mac. There is a [windows solution](http://dyslexiclikeme.org/products/%E2%80%A2-other-4/), and a [paid solution](http://www.dyslexic.com/claroread-plus-mac), but I'm looking for a free, cheap or built in way to achieve the same result. I've googled, and found a couple [discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1795191?threadID=1795191) but no solution.

Are any of you aware of any software or system preferences I can use to either:

- tint the whole screen a colour (ideal)
- change the background colour of windows / documents to one similar to the tint (better than nothing)
- achieve a comparable result.

If you have dyslexia and have found a workaround for this challenge I'd be really grateful for your input as well!

I thought that this would be achievable with the color setting in System Preferences but I don't think it allows the tinting sense. I might be wrong though.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use it for this, but it's one of the options available in [Black Light](http://michelf.com/projects/black-light/).  You might also be able to create a custom color profile (System Preferences > Displays > Color > Calibrate...) in expert mode, but unless you can do it just by tweaking the color temperature or gamma then it'll probably require some expertise to adjust the color curves.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest that you look at [Nocturne](http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-nocturne/):

[image: Nocturne preferences]

It allows you to invert the screen colors and create a night mode, which is much easier on the eyes.  It is also under the apache license, so open source and free to use.

Comment: Upvoted for Nocturne.  I use it just for night mode (aka "battle stations").

Comment: Nocturne is the [weapon of choice for me, too](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/12719/1453)

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) Thanks!   I found it's [latest release on GitHub](https://github.com/nocturneapp/nocturne/releases) in both binary and source forms (while a lot of other tools cost money just to install).

Answer (score 1):

I know this may be a bit off-topic, but have you checked out [this font for dyslexics](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLtYFcHx7ec)
?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for (and this is an old thread so you might have already found a solution) - I have dyslexia and find that a coloured overlay helps me read so I created a small, open source Java program to create an overlay on screen. It can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tintedwindow/). Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try   <kbd>[image: control]</kbd><kbd>[image: option]</kbd><kbd>[image]</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd>. That should invert the colors.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the same thing. So far the only solution I have been able to come up with is only applicable in **Word**. If you go to `Format and Background` you can change the colour of the "paper". This setting does not apply during printing so you won't accidentally waste all your ink.

I know I have the ability to get software free through my university, though I don't know if it serves this function — have you contacted the suppliers to see if they will offer your school free/discount services?

Maybe you could contact the British Dyslexia association about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this is an old thread so you might already found a solution. Although it doesn't fully change the whole screen's colour (it's more like a reading bar with tinted colour), the app [Overlays!](https://abbiecod.es/apps) is a completely free app that enables to partially change the background colour. It is customizable so you can change the overlay colour and its opacity. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to this, with OSX Monterrey.

System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Color Filters

- filter type: tint
- intensity
- color

There are also built-in profiles for **tritanopia, deuteranopia, and protanopia**.

[image: tinting accessibility screens menu]